# MySQL database table creation is very slow

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I´ve run a test script that creates a database and 3 sample tables.

Machine: Windows 7 x64 and MariaDB 10.0.17

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbTest;
CREATE DATABASE dbTest;
USE dbTest;

SET profiling = 1;

CREATE TABLE table1 (
    var1 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    var2 VARCHAR (100) COLLATE ucs2_bin,
    var3 BIGINT,
    var4 BIGINT,
    var5 BIGINT) ENGINE = InnoDB;


    CREATE TABLE table2 (
        var1 BIGINT NOT NULL,
        var2 BIGINT,
        var3 VARCHAR(1000) COLLATE ucs2_bin,
        var4 BIGINT) ENGINE = InnoDB;
   INSERT INTO table2 (var1, var2) VALUES (1, 0);


  CREATE TABLE table3 (
       var1 BIGINT NOT NULL,
       var2 VARCHAR (100) COLLATE ucs2_bin,
       var3 INT,
       var4 INT
  ) ENGINE = InnoDB;


  SET profiling = 1;
```

If I run this script in my MariaDB 10.0 installation (default settings), it takes **2,688 seconds**.

Reviewing the profile of the CREATE TABLE query, most of the time is being cosnsumed "creating table" (used HeidiSQL).

[image]

If I try to create bigger databases, the query time increases a lot. It´s too much and it doesn´t make sense to me.

On the other hand, if I run the same queries in SQL Server, it takes only milliseconds.

I don´t think that it´s a hard drive issue.

[image]

I think that there is something wrong with the database configuration that makes the operation so slow.

PD: In a coworker´s machine (same MariaDB version), the operation takes 2,5 seconds as well.

Comment: Try creating them as "MyISAM", so you know if this is an InnoDB related issue.

Comment: Also can you tell us the exact MariaDB version (is it 10.0.10, 10.0.11, some other?) and the OS and edition flavour you use (Windows 8 64bit, XP 32bit, Linux Ubunutu 14.04, Debian 6, ...)

Comment: I would also test running the sql script (that creates the database and tables) from the cli as well (just to check if it is a client connection/drivers issue between HeidiSQL and MariaDB).

Comment: Added more detailed info, and also I ran the script using the CLI, but not luck :(

Comment: A table requires 1-3 files in a directory.  On Windows, creating files is a slow process.  How many other tables already in the same database?  What is the value of `innodb_file_per_table`?

Comment: I´ve tested the same script in SQL Server and is very fast, so it shoudn´t be related to Windows vs Linux. I´m going to review the "innodb_file_per_table" value as well to check if modifying it could help.

Comment: Shouldn't the second `SET profiling = 1;` be `SET profiling = 0;` instead ?